# PL/SQL - returning with cursor that is used to update throws "fetch out of sequence"

Tags: oracle, select, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have the following SP, but I want to have the cursor as an OUT parameter after using that for updating the records. As a result an *ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence* is thrown. Autocommit is off by default, so there is obviously no problem with that.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE MY_PROC( 
    my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
    myId my_table.id%type;
BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR 
      SELECT id FROM my_table
      FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
    LOOP 
        FETCH my_cursor INTO myId;
        EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        UPDATE my_table SET lastSelected = SYSTIMESTAMP
        WHERE id = myId;
    END LOOP;
END MY_PROC;
```

I spent way too much time on this without success, so I assume it cannot be solved this way. I'd be glad if you gave me a hint.

Thanks in advance, Gergely

Comment: A cursor can only move forward through the rows. Your procedure is reading all the cursor rows, so by the time you return it, it's at EOF. Because the cursor is forward-only it can't be set back to BOF. You could try re-executing the cursor query after the LOOP/UPDATE if you're confident you'll get the same result set. Or you could query the return cursor based on the `lastSelected` timestamp value. Also note that you may need to define two cursors - one for the loop/update and one for the return value.

Comment: Why dont you create another cursor inside your proc to traverse and update the data then open your cursor after you do the update. Of course this would do the trick unless you want to have a snapshot of the data before you updated it?

Comment: Guys, Great answers, Thank you very much. This is the thing I assumed: that EOF, but I didn't find a proving source. Why didn't you answered normally... then I could accept it. :D Thanks again, you saved me!!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Beside the actual answer to your problem (which I won't repeat here by courtesy towards Ed Gibbs) I think your SP needs to be revised.

While you open your cursor to retrieve every single ID in your table, for each record found, you update *all* the table:

```
UPDATE my_table SET lastSelected = SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

What you wanted to do was probably:

```
UPDATE my_table SET lastSelected = SYSTIMESTAMP WHERE id = myId;
```

Hope it helped.
S.

Comment: Thanks for the note. It was my fault. I use the "WHERE"-clause as well, just forgot to copy here. (just updated)